# HDMI not working while plugging in Power charger to the laptop (works fine with battery only)

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi, power, charger

I have an Acer Aspire 6930 with Nvidia 9600m GT GPU, there is a weird issue that occurs when I connect the Acer Aspire to an LG TV with HDMI cable... the Laptop recognizes the TV and everything seems to work but there is no display showing on the TV. I accidentally discovered that whenever I disconnect the charger from the laptop, the HDMI works fine while using laptop over battery.

So what I'm asking is are there any settings that I could change so that HDMI works while plugged in?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Windows remembers certain power and display settings when plugged in or when running on battery and makes those changes on the fly. So when you plug in the charger and the screen does not show up, have you verified that the display settings are the same as when it's not plugged in?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to know, if there is a certain power settings for display only to compare them

Answer (score 0):

This post is pretty old so you may have discovered this already.
HDMI connections are very sensitive to electrical current.  When you plug in the adapter make sure that you keep the electrical wiring away from the the HDMI cable.  Sounds simple but it's important.